# How not to count array.push(undefined) with array.forEach(_ => count++)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My goal is to push actual `undefined` to an Array, similar to `new Array()`. Right now, if you use `array.push(undefined)` and count it with `array.forEach(element => count++)` it is still counted as element.

```
function test() {
  let object = [5,,,5,"hoomba"]
  object.push(undefined)
  let maxRetries = 0;
  object.forEach(element => maxRetries++);

  console.log(object);
  console.log(maxRetries);
}

test();
```

Expected result:

```
console.log(object) // [5, undefined, undefined, 5, "hoomba", undefined]
console.log(maxRetries) // 3
```

Actual result:

```
console.log(object) // [5, undefined, undefined, 5, "hoomba", undefined]
console.log(maxRetries) // 4
```

Comment: What's stopping you to doing something like this, `if (element !== undefined) maxRetries++`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the check for `undefined` (or falsy value) before count.

`element !== undefined && maxRetries++`

```js
function test() {
  let object = [5,,,5,"hoomba"]
  object.push(undefined)
  let maxRetries = 0;
  object.forEach(element => element !== undefined && maxRetries++);
  
  // Alternatively add falsy value (null, undefined, 0, '')
  // object.forEach(element => element && maxRetries++);

  console.log(object);
  console.log(maxRetries);
}

test();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the `undefined` values and count the `length`

```js
function test() {
  let object = [5,,,5,"hoomba"]
  object.push(undefined)
  
  const maxRetries = object.filter(v => v !== undefined).length

  console.log('object:', object);
  console.log('maxRetries:', maxRetries);
}

test();
```